# handler or chronometer or timertask or countdowntimer which I should use for showing countdowntimer in UI and doing some operation after time is up?

Tags: java, android

I am doing a quiz application in android, which should exit after the time allotted for that quiz is over and calculate the score when time is up or user pressed submit.For the time up score calculation scenario which one I should use timertask or countdowntimer or handler or chronometer.I would need to show a countdown timer as well until time up. Now after the answers I am further confused.Please suggest.

Comment: you can use chronometere

Comment: neither one,  use a Handler

Comment: You have to try the runnable after every second and count in some variable and fix it maxmum size for example 100 after 100s you cancel first you runnable and then perform your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), here's an example:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```

If you'd like to terminate the handler at any time, you can call:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

From the docs:

```
public final void removeCallbacksAndMessages (Object token)

Added in API level 1
Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.
```

Comment: How will you stop this handler before 100ms (As OP want stop if user press submit and he also want to show time lft )

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal By simply calling handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable); I've edited the answer with a reference to the API as well. :)

Comment: Why is handler preferred over Timer/TimerTask and the much simpler CountDownTimer and Chronometer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function on your onCreate and do stuff on onFinish of countdown

```
public void startTicking() {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timerinterval, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // do stuff here
            }
        };
    }
```